# Pyglet. Issue with wide image. 8192/8193px

Tags: python, python-3.x, opengl, image-processing, pyglet

#### Env:

Ubuntu 18.04
python 3.6.6
library: pyglet==1.3.2

#### Source code:

[repository on github](https://github.com/Yuriy-Leonov/Pyglet_wide_image_issue)
There is two images: 
1) 8192x1px.png 
2) 8193x1px.png

```
import pyglet

GOOD_FILE = "8192x1px.png"
BAD_FILE = "8193x1px.png"

image_8192x1px = pyglet.image.load(GOOD_FILE)
image_grid_8192x1px = pyglet.image.ImageGrid(image=image_8192x1px, rows=1, columns=1)
texture_grid_8192x1px = image_grid_8192x1px.get_texture_sequence()

image_8193x1px = pyglet.image.load(BAD_FILE)
image_grid_8193x1px = pyglet.image.ImageGrid(image=image_8193x1px, rows=1, columns=1)
texture_grid_8193x1px = image_grid_8193x1px.get_texture_sequence()
```

Exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 12, in <module>
    texture_grid_8193x1px = image_grid_8193x1px.get_texture_sequence()
  File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyglet/image/__init__.py", line 2308, in get_texture_sequence
    self._texture_grid = TextureGrid(self)
  File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyglet/image/__init__.py", line 2379, in __init__
    image = grid.get_texture()
  File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyglet/image/__init__.py", line 2301, in get_texture
    return self.image.get_texture(rectangle, force_rectangle)
  File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyglet/image/__init__.py", line 859, in get_texture
    force_rectangle)
  File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyglet/image/__init__.py", line 844, in create_texture
    rectangle, force_rectangle)
  File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyglet/image/__init__.py", line 1564, in create
    blank)
  File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyglet/gl/lib.py", line 105, in errcheck
    raise GLException(msg)
pyglet.gl.lib.GLException: b'invalid value'
```

#### Questions:

What is the reason of failing on image with 8193px(or any other value of width more than 8192px) width? (where is no matter of height, I've tested from 1px to 900px)
How to avoid/fix that?

PS: Difference between images is only in 1 px wide.

#### Update:

As was mentioned in comment: GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE shows restriction of max width*height in px for texture. And it's not editable per device.

Comment: What does your OpenGL implementation report for [`GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGet.xhtml)?

Comment: @genpfault 8192 :) Ok, as I read - there is no simple way to change it